# PHP/MYSQL timesheet calculate hours from in and out

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched high and low and have found many answers but nothing cut and dry for my situation.
I'm working on a very simple timesheet (PHP/MYSQL) for only a couple of employees. Only a few fields to enter "Location" "Description" "Timein" "Timeout". What I need to do is take the timein and timeout and find how many hours. For display purposes I'm using a dropdown list for the timein/timeout which values have been created from the strtotime() function incrementing every half hour.

```
echo '<select name="timein">';
$start=strtotime('7:00am');
$end=strtotime('8:00pm');
for ($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i+=1800)
{echo '<option value="'.date('g:i a',$i).'">'.date('g:i a',$i).'</option>';}
echo '</select>';
```

when I try to insert those into my database I get an incorrect time value error (should I have the timein as a varchar?) None the less I just need a way to take timein (9am) timeout (2pm) and get the 5 hours from it.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO sheet(employee, date, location, description, timein, timeout)
VALUES('$employee', NOW(), '$location', '$description', '$timein', '$timeout')")or die(mysql_error());
```

- employee varchar(30)
- date date
- location text
- timein time
- timeout time
- timespent int(10)
- totalhours int(10)

Comment: I don't think the format of the timestamp is correct depending on how you created the column. Can you show us the query and the table structure.

Comment: also missing value=""

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `</option>` and your options don't have a value, just a label.

`<select>` should look like this:

```
<select name="timein">
    <option value="0">8:00am</option>
    <option value="1">9:00am</option>
    <option value="2">10:00am</option>
    <option value="3">11:00am</option>
    <!-- etc -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date column is expecting something like `'0000-00-00'`  but the mysql function `now()` returns Timestamp like `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` try `CURDATE()` instead.

Also your date format isn't correct for what mysql expects for Time. `'00:00:00'`
you should try `date("H:i:s", $i)` when creating the value for each option.  You can still use the date format you have for the text portion. (The text the user would see.)

Comment: Thanks. I have found weither using NOW() or CURDATE() that the dbase shows 4/9/2013 12:00:00 AM regardless - moot point. The time thing did help, now my dbase is showing 15:00:00 rather than 3:00 pm still have to figure out how to calculate the hours worked though.

Comment: Just Subtract.  $timeout - $timein = timeworked (in seconds) just format it with date function to show it in the format you desire.